# hg repository via mac with terminal

Tags: macos, mercurial, terminal, clone

I would like to know how to clone a repository from my own internal server via terminal.

We have different servers in our office and I can access them via FINDER but when I'm trying to do this via terminal, I'm in troubles.

hg clone ????? myLocalFolder/myClonedRepo

what do i put in ?????

hg clone 192.168.???.???/remoteRepo myLocalFolder/myClonedRepo

Thanks in advance

Sergio

I have to add details ab my question. I'm on a mac and my is a window server. I can't use SSH protocol

Comment: This question has nothing to do with mercurial at all. It is all about network basics and mac.

Comment: I know, but maybe someone has solved this problem

Comment: `this problem` is all about network basics. Don't confuse people with additional pointless information about mercurial. Just ask short question about how to get an access to the files on remote computer using command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the mounted drives should be accessible through the <kbd>/Volumes/wathever</kbd> path.